# Understanding of z axis

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have 2 triangles with cords:

```
static float squareCoords[] = {  
    // red triangle
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f,
    0.25f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f,

    //black triangle
    -0.1f, -0.1f, 0.1f,
    0.15f, 0.4f, 0.1f,
    0.4f, -0.1f, 0.1f,
};
```

Drawing order:

```
private short drawOrder[] = { 
            0, 2, 1,
            3, 5, 4,
    };
```

Then I draw it with glDrawElements and black triangle is always in front of red. Changing Z coordinates has no results. Seems like it draws black tringle second, that is why it is always in front. Help me to uderstand what is going on and where is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are not enabling depth testing via `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`?

Alternatively, your projection matrix may be set up such that the Z coordinates are getting "squished" together during conversion to normalized device coordinates.  Check what your near and far plane are and possibly pull the far plane in or the near plane out.

Comment: There is no projection matrix, GL_DEPTH_TEST helped. So OpenGL just draw elements by order ignoring z coordinate if GL_DEPTH_TEST or Projection matrix are not set?

Comment: Yes; without depth testing objects will contribute to the frame buffer in submission order, with newer things overwriting older things.  Either the projection matrix (in fixed function pipelines) or the actions of the shaders (in programmable pipelines; often the concept of a projection matrix is still maintained, just baked into the shader) define which input coordinates produce which output coordinates.  In the case of GL_DEPTH_TEST being enabled, that transformation into output/NDC space can cause things to be "close enough" to z-fight or order differently than you'd expect.

Comment: With depth testing, the newer objects will either contribute to the frame buffer or not on a per-fragment basis, based on what depth function (`glDepthFunc`) you're using.  So the default depth function -- `GL_LESS` -- "Passes if the incoming depth value is less than the stored depth value".  This is after transformation -- if you're looking down the -Z axis in world coordinates, this means a *greater* z value will be in front.  See also `gluLookAt` etc.  =)

Comment: You may find this series very helpful!  http://tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/03-matrices-depth-buffering-animation/

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with continued 3d graphics adventures!  =)